# Usage of adjectival form versus nominal form

Tags: grammar

If I am right, in 'an English phrase' 'English' is an adjectival form while in 'a phrase in English', 'English' is a nominal form.

Should I say 'An English overview of this topic' or 'An overview in English of this topic' ?

Comment: _An overview of this topic in English_ sounds more natural.

Comment: Yes, indeed, it sounds even clearer than 'an overview in English of this topic'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [**Eng·lish**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/English)  (*adj*.)
>   1. Of, relating to, or characteristic of England or its people or culture.
>   2. Of or relating to the English language.

The word *English* has more than one definition, so I might assume those two sentences don't necessarily have the same meaning.

> *An overview in English of this topic*

That plainly means the overview is presented in English.

> *An English overview of this topic*

That could mean the overview is presented from a British perspective, related to England's people and culture. I might expect to see a dash of *localised humour*, for example.

Comment: One more thing : English is also a noun, according to the Oxford dictionay.

1 the West Germanic language of England, now widely used in many varieties throughout the world.

Comment: @Brice - Yes, my pasted definition here is abridged. A more complete definition can be found using the provided link.